# How to add data to product item line on order preview

Tags: php, wordpress

With a plugin, on the order preview (by clicking on the little eye ^^), I would like to add "the line number" or "order item" for each of the products in the invoice.

I'm editing this post again because I had a perhaps better idea which is to add a new column to the table that displays product details.

My following code displays the new connection correctly, the HTML structure of the table is correct, however, for each product line, the column data is not displayed. (I used random text to avoid possible data recovery problems)

```
// Ajouter le contenu personnalisé à la ligne du tableau pour chaque produit dans la modale de prévisualisation de commande WooCommerce
function custom_wc_order_preview_table_content($item, $args) {
    // Vérifier si l'élément est un produit
    if ($item->is_type('line_item')) {
        // Générer un texte aléatoire pour tester
        $random_text = substr(str_shuffle("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"), 0, 5);

        // Afficher le texte aléatoire dans la nouvelle colonne
        if ('new' === $args['column_id']) {
            echo '<td class="wc-order-preview-table__column--new">'; // Nouvelle colonne
            echo $random_text; // Affichage du texte aléatoire
            echo '</td>';
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_column', 'custom_wc_order_preview_table_content', 10, 2);

// Modifier l'ordre des colonnes dans le tableau de prévisualisation des commandes
function custom_wc_order_preview_table_header($columns) {
    // Ajouter la nouvelle colonne en seconde position
    $new_columns = array('new' => __('Nouvelle colonne', 'woocommerce'));
    $columns = array_slice($columns, 0, 1, true) + $new_columns + array_slice($columns, 1, count($columns) - 1, true);
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_columns', 'custom_wc_order_preview_table_header');

// Modifier la largeur des colonnes dans le tableau de prévisualisation des commandes
function custom_wc_order_preview_table_css() {
    echo '<style>.wc-order-preview-table__column--new { width: 20%; }</style>';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'custom_wc_order_preview_table_css');
```

(Sorry for the comments in French)

I don't know if it's clear but thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You need to show your code in the post, not as a photo. Show us what you've tried, and a description of what the specific problem was.

Comment: you need woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details to modify the content there - https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_admin_order_preview_get_order_details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't know if I should edit my previous post to give an answer but I think giving a new answer is better because you can mark it as solved.*

Thank you to those who searched even without finding or giving results but I found a solution that suits me (to see if it will suit my boss when I return from this vacation ^^):

```
// Add new column
function filter_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_columns( $columns, $order ) { 
    // Add a new column
    $new_column['info'] = __( 'n°', 'woocommerce' );

    // Return new column as first
    return $new_column + $columns;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_columns', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_columns', 10, 2 );

function filter_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_column_info( $html, $item, $item_id, $order ) {
    // Get line item ID
    $line_item_id = $item_id;

    // Display line item ID as info
    $html = '#' . $line_item_id;

    return $html;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_column_info', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_order_preview_line_item_column_info', 10, 4 );

// CSS style
function add_order_notes_column_style() {
    $css = '.wc-order-preview .wc-order-preview-table td, .wc-order-preview .wc-order-preview-table th { text-align: left; } .wc-order-preview-table__column--info { padding-right: 0!important; width: 40px; }';
    wp_add_inline_style( 'woocommerce_admin_styles', $css );
}
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'add_order_notes_column_style' );
```

Thank you all